# How can I create a folder with a new text file in it from the command line?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I'm a reporter who uses the following command to create a story folder with subfolders for each new story I begin:

```
/bin/mkdir -p ~/Desktop/NewStory/{Copy,Data,Notes,PubMaterial,RefMaterial,Media/{Audio,Images,Video}}
```

It works like a charm, but I'd also like to create a text file in the "Data" subfolder called "DataJournal.txt" and I don't know how to do that.

Going one step further, I'd like to add the four headings of my data journals:

> ---Data Folder Setup
>
> ---Data Introduction
>
> ---Data Audit/Manipulation
>
> ---Data Queries

I can create such a text file now using an echo command but I have no idea how to work this into the command that creates the folders/subfolders. I'd be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrap the entire thing into a shell script and execute that instead of the `mkdir` command.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z "${1}" ]]; then
  die "FolderName Required"
fi


/bin/mkdir -p ~/Desktop/$1/{Copy,Data,Notes,PubMaterial,RefMaterial,Media/{Audio,Images,Video}}

echo -n "---Data Folder Setup

---Data Introduction

---Data Audit/Manipulation

---Data Queries" > ~/Desktop/$1/Data/DataJournal.txt
```

Adding a little generality the use of this script would be `bash script-name.sh StoryName` as `$1` is interpolated into the first argument passed to the script. ( Or just `./script-name.sh StoryName` if you happened to `chmod +x` it so it is executable ).

Comment: Better still, you can make it more general and pass the value of NewStory in as a parameter.

Comment: Very true, I find there is a trade off between correctness and speed. I can update this to take parameters if jeff so deems it necessary.

Comment: I would love to see that. Thanks so much!

Comment: My answer below takes the story name as a parameter - but this answer has a nicer way of handling the newlines :)

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr, You forgot to add code to check for a parameter!  If executed without one, it will create ~/Desktop/{Copy,Data,Notes,PubMaterial,RefMaterial} and etc.!

Comment: Thank you! I earned my student badge with this one and I'm glad for all the teachers.

Comment: Congrats Jeff, don't forget to accept an answer and welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: I will totally do that and thanks! All of the answers are being updated so fast I'm still trying to keep up!

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do it on one line, you can chain commands together with `&&`, but you're probably better off putting it in a shell script of its own:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then echo "No name specified."; exit; fi;
/bin/mkdir -p ~/Desktop/$1/{Copy,Data,Notes,PubMaterial,RefMaterial,Media/{Audio,Images,Video}}
echo -n "---Data Folder Setup

---Data Introduction

---Data Audit/Manipulation

---Data Queries" > ~/Desktop/$1/Data/DataJournal.txt
```

If you put this into say `create-story.sh`, then you can invoke it with `./create-story.sh NewStory`. Don't forget to make it executable with `chmod +x create-story.sh`.

Comment: This is great. It's wonderful to be able to name the folder this way. There's just one problem, when I open the DataJournal.txt file it has this in it: ---Data Folder Setup \n\n--Data Introduction....

Comment: Sorry - swap out the echo line for the multi-line echo in other answers. I'll update my answer :)

Comment: Add the -e parameter to echo [enable escape chars], and it will work.

Comment: The updated version should work a treat. If you want to, you can even go a step further and open up the DataJournal file by adding something like `gedit ~/Desktop/$1/Data/DataJournal.txt` to the end of the script.

Comment: And if executed without any parameters? $1 would equal "", thus creating tons of folders, where they should not be.. [Right on the desktop]

Comment: Updated version is great. Thanks! Learned a bunch this morning.

Comment: @Matt Well spotted. I added the error checking from your answer and gave you an upvote. High fives all around!

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be doing this a lot, I would create a script.  [Or you could also make this a function and put it in your .bashrc]

Copy & paste this into a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then echo "No name specified."; exit; fi;
mkdir -p ~/Desktop/"$1"/{Copy,Data,Notes,PubMaterial,RefMaterial,Media/{Audio,Images,Video}}
echo '---Data Folder Setup

---Data Introduction

---Data Audit/Manipulation

---Data Queries' > ~/Desktop/"$1"/Data/DataJournal.txt
exit 0
```

Save this somewhere as "newstory", or whatever you like in your home folder [~/]
Open a terminal and type [UPDATED] `chmod +x newstory; sudo mv newstory /usr/games/`  /usr/games/ is  usually in your $PATH variable, so when you type "newstory" it knows where to look for it and executes it.  **Note** [as of now] The other answers here do not have error protection, so if you execute the script without the parameter [$1] It will simply make all the directories in your ~/Desktop/ directory!

**Now** you are all done!  Next time you want to add a new directory with all the sub directories and the DataJournal.txt with the header, open your terminal and type `newstory "Name Of Story"`!  Be sure to quote it if you have spaces in the name, otherwise it will only catch the first word.

P.S. if you want to use a function in your .bashrc instead, just wrap the above code [Except the '#!/bin/bash' in a function, added to ~/.bashrc: `newstory () { ***paste code here*** *;* }

Comment: Your #! won't work unless your bash is chilling on the root of your drive.

Comment: Okay, when I entered the sudo command, I got this back: mv: rename newstory to /usr/games/: Permission denied

Comment: @Jeff, sorry about that, please try the updated code. Thanks :)

Comment: Matt - you have extra `"` characters around the `$1` which will also cause problems

Comment: @Matt, could you have a look at one more error message? This time ran sudo and got this: su: illegal option -- c
usage: su [-] [-flm] [login [args]]

Comment: @Timothy, how so? Quotes around input variables are usually advised [at least, that's what I've heard].  I've had scripts/functions screw up because of unquoted variables [with odd characters and such].  And I see nothing wrong with "$1"/{a,b,c}. Try it: $ a=Test; echo "$a"/{a,b,c,d/{e,f,g}}

Comment: @Jeff... So sorry; I updated it again, please try it once more!  This time it cannot fail.